# Django unknown password hashing algorithm - writing a custom hashing alghorithm

Tags: django, authentication, hash, passwords

I migrated users from other site to django site. Old web page had md5 passwords with salt and I am writing a custom hashing alghorithm to so users may authenticate with their old passwords.

When I am trying to login as old user I get:

```
Unknown password hashing algorithm 'my_hashed_password'. Did you specify it in the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?
```

Thats my password hasher

```
class FallbackMD5PasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):

    algorithm = "fallback_md5"

    def salt(self):
        return 'my_salt'

    def encode(self, password):
        return hashlib.md5(self.salt() + password).hexdigest()

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        encoded_2 = self.encode(password, '')
        return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)

    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        return SortedDict([
            (_('algorithm'), self.algorithm),
            (_('hash'), mask_hash(encoded, show=3)),
        ])
```

Thats my settings.py

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'lfs_custom.hasher.FallbackMD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
    )
```

Please provide me some info how to fix this :) I can't find it out why its not working.

Comment: where does the string "my_hashed_password" comes from? can you lookup the project files?

Comment: That string is a hashed password in my database which is returned in error on login.

Answer (score 3):

Django tries to parse hash from your database using this [format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/):

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

You likely have plain hashes in database. Try to execute an SQL on database to update with correct format, something like:

```
update auth_user set password=concat("md5$1$", password);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need this
{

class FallbackMD5PasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
   algorithm = "fallback_md5"
   iterations = 100000
   def salt(self):
        return ''

```
def encode(self, password, salt):
    assert salt == ''
    hash= hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
    return "%s$%d$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, self.iterations, '', hash)

def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm

    encoded_2 = self.encode(password, '')
    return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)

def safe_summary(self, encoded):
    algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
    return SortedDict([
        (_('algorithm'), algorithm),
        (_('iterations'), iterations),
        (_('salt'), mask_hash(salt)),
        (_('hash'), mask_hash(hash)),
    ])

def must_update(self, encoded):
    return True
```

}